# Как использовать GDI+ шрифт для edit контрола?

Tags: c++, gdi+

```
Main::Main(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
    int       nCmdShow)
{

INT                   found = 0;
FontFamily*           pFontFamily;
PrivateFontCollection privateFontCollection;
privateFontCollection.AddFontFile(L"C:\\WINNT\\Fonts\\font.ttf");
privateFontCollection.GetFamilies(1, pFontFamily, &found);
Font* pFont = new Font(familyName, 16, FontStyleRegular,
                             UnitPixel, &privateFontCollection);


    hwndEdit= CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        L"EDIT",
        L"",
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_MULTILINE,
        100,100, 230, 50,
        hWnd, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr
    );
```

**Обновлено.**

Загрузка:

```
    LOGFONTA lf;
    pFont ->GetLogFontA(gt,&lf);
    lf.lfHeight = 18; // По высоте.
    HFONT hFont = CreateFontIndirectA(&lf);
    SendMessage(input, WM_SETFONT, WPARAM(hFont), 0L);
}
```

Все данные получаются, кроме самого шрифта, он стоковый, но размер, высота - передаются из pFont

```
bool  loadFontIntoCollection(PrivateFontCollection* collection, int id)
{
    HRSRC hres = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(id), RT_RCDATA);
    if (hres)
    {
        HGLOBAL mem = LoadResource(NULL, hres);
        void* data = LockResource(mem);
        size_t size = SizeofResource(NULL, hres);
        Gdiplus::Status result = collection->AddMemoryFont(data, size);
        if (result == Gdiplus::Ok) {
            return true; 
        }
    }
    return false;
}
WM_CREATE:

bool a = loadFontIntoCollection(&normalFontCollection, IDR_RCDATA3);
    int nNumFound = 0;
    FontFamily font;
    PrivateFontCollection normalFontCollection.GetFamilies(1, &font, &nNumFound);

    if (nNumFound == 0)
        throw std::logic_error("No font!");

    Font* fontLato = new Font(&font, 18, FontStyleRegular, UnitPixel);
```

Comment: Видимо, нужно в SendMessage использовать хендл шрифта, а не указатель на какой то левый класс-обертку.

Comment: @KoVadim и как его получить?

Comment: @KoVadim обновил

Comment: вот второй кусок кода вроде должен работать. тут вот примеры есть https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221411/how-can-i-specify-a-font-for-a-window-created-through-createwindow

Comment: @KoVadim, мне бы именно через gdi+, тк сейчас я добавил функцию, который будет загружать в память шрифт через файлы ресурсов. Обновил код, добавил функцию

Comment: а эти классы - PrivateFontCollection - это с++/cli?

Comment: @KoVadim PrivateFontCollection class (gdiplusheaders.h)